# angular.dart how to create a custom component programmatically and add to page?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Is it possible to define an angular-dart component and then programmatically create an instance of that component and add it to your web page? I'd hoped there might be something like:

```dart
import 'package:web_sandbox/web_sandbox.dart';
import 'package:angular/angular.dart' as ng;

void main() {
  document.body.appendHtml('<web-sandbox-component></web-sandbox-component>');
  var node = document.body.query('web-sandbox-component');
  ng.compile(node);
}
```

is there away of creating an angular web component programmatically and adding it to the page, maybe like the above pseudo-example, and if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with Angular.

You can add an HTML tag `<web-sandbox-component>` into the DOM and tell Angular it should process this new HTML and then Angular would instantiate the Angular component for this tag (this is what the question you linked is about).

I don't see this as a limitation. 
Is there something you would like to do that seems not possible this way?.

**EDIT**

Your code in main should look like this:

my document looks like

```dart
...
<body>
  <div id="mydiv"></div>
  ...
</body>
```

and I append the `<web-sandbox-component>` to the div

```dart
main() {
  print('main');
  ng.Injector inj = ngaf.applicationFactory().addModule(new MyAppModule()).run();
  var node = dom.querySelector('#mydiv');
  node.append(new dom.Element.html('<web-sandbox-component></web-sandbox-component>', validator: new dom.NodeValidatorBuilder()..allowCustomElement("web-sandbox-component")));
  ng.Compiler compiler = inj.get(ng.Compiler);
  ng.DirectiveMap directiveMap = inj.get(ng.DirectiveMap);
  compiler(node.childNodes, directiveMap)(inj, node.childNodes);
}
```

Comment: no, that's basically the same thing, I just didn't fully understand what that other question was about with the extending off NgShadowDomAware

Comment: `implements NgShadowDomAware` just tells Angular to call `onShadowRoot` when the shadow DOM is ready. This is basically the time when the content of the component is ready to interact with.

Comment: so if I call `document.body.appendHtml('<web-sandbox-component></web-sandbox-component>');` will angular auto detect the dom change and populate it with my components template shadow dom?

Comment: No, you have to call compile on the new HTML to make Angular 'process' it. This is what the answers in the question you linked are about.

Comment: thanks that looks great, I'll try it out when I get home and accept the answer then, just for those that don't know (like me) what is the `MyAppModule` and how do I define one?

Comment: You "need" a module (can be any class name) to register your custom components/decorators. see https://angulardart.org/tutorial/04-ch02-controller.html for more details (in the code snippes in section "Understanding @Controller controllers")

Comment: ah cool, so its just where you register up all your custom components/directicves/controllers/etc in the constructor of a class that extends ng.Module