# How to add a html with angular-dart component using Decorator

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have my custom decorator like from the tutorial which adds HTML code to a page.
But if HTML code contains my custom component  it will not be processed by AngularDart.
How can I add a processed component from a decorator?

Comment: possible duplicate of [angular.dart how to create a custom component programmatically and add to page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23184009/angular-dart-how-to-create-a-custom-component-programmatically-and-add-to-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components can't be added dynamically. Instead, use ng-hide with a bool value to toggle it.
Then you can use your decorator to update the value upon your needs.

Comment: In fact components can be added dynamically. This is done in many places (for example views)
See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23184009 for an example or this Q/A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20423565 (may be a bit outdated because of continually changing AnguldarDart API).